# Visual Studio Key Strokes: Swapping lines

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

Is there a keystroke in visual studio similar to Eclipse's <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>?

For example:

```
int x = 0; // Cursor is anywhere on this line.
int y = 1;
```

and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> were pressed, then:

```
int y = 1;
int x = 0; // Cursor is anywhere on this line.
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

VS 2013 and later:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> (`Edit.MoveSelectedLinesUp`)

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> (`Edit.MoveSelectedLinesDown`)

---

VS 2012:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>T</kbd> 
(`Edit.LineTranspose`)

but this only swaps between the current and the next line (move down only).

VS 2012 does not support macros but there is the [Productivity Power Tools 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) extension that adds (besides some other nice features) commands to move a line up or down with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>.

---

VS 2010 and earlier:

Line transpose works (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>T</kbd>) but still no move up.

You could write a macro for those commands, I think this question may help you: [Visual Studio: hotkeys to move line up/down and move through recent changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/313462/303427)

Comment: alt + Up / Down still valid in Visual Studio 2017, +1

Comment: those commands are not associated in my install of VS2019.

Answer (score 16):

As of Visual Studio 2013, you can simply use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>↓</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

For **Mac**, It is: <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>↓</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative solution, you could write a Visual Studio Extension to do this for you. Extensions are written in your favorite .NET language.

Refer to the MSDN article on creating [Visual Studio Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885119.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Alt + Up/Down arrow in Windows.
Be aware that this shortcut is not listed in the official Visual Studio Code keyboard shorcut for Windows yet (https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)