# htaccess redirection keeps domain structure

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

This is my htaccess, default wp htaccess and adding a simple Redirect 301 redirects into the wrong destination

```
Redirect 301 /de/konnektivitat /connect/
Redirect 301 /de/konnektivitat/detail /connect/

# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

The issue is that when going to `/de/konnektivitat/detail` redirects me `/connect//detail`

Comment: Did you not go read up on how the `Redirect` directive actually works? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect: _"any request **beginning with** URL-path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. **Additional path information beyond the matched URL-path will be appended to the target URL.**"_

Comment: You request `/de/konnektivitat/detail`, the`/de/konnektivitat` in your first directive matches that already. So the new target URL will be `/connect/`, plus the excess part of the requested URL, which is `/detail` in this case. Put these directives in reverse order; or use RedirectMatch to begin with, to do both in one go.

Comment: @CBroe can you help me find a fix? I'm not sure what I'm missing. I need that `/de/konnektivitat/detail/` go to `/connect/`

Comment: "Put these directives in reverse order; or use RedirectMatch to begin with, to do both in one go." I can't put them in reverse order because I have a few hundred redirects

Comment: _"because I have a few hundred redirects"_ - and what does that have to do with not being able to reverse the order in which _two_ of those are written in? You need to explain your problem _properly_, not make bogus "because" claims. What are those other redirects then, are they also for URLs starting with `/de/konnektivitat`? If not, then I don't see how the argument you just tried to make here has _any_ relevance.

Comment: @CBroe i meant I have hundreds of redirects similar to this one, all with the same issue. I cannot take every pair of lines to reverse their order

Comment: If you want to rewrite _anything_ that starts with `/de/konnektivitat`, then you can do that with  `RedirectMatch`, using a pattern that is anchored at the start. (That would of course also redirect `/de/konnektivitat/foobar` then - which your original code did not do. Whether you'd want that or not, you'd have to tell us.)

Comment: But that doesn't change the fact that you will have to replace all of your hundreds of redirects with something else anyway. Sorry, but there is most likely no way out of "did it fundamentally wrong to begin with" here, that would _not_ require you to change all of it. (Unless some sort of pattern could be identified, that would allow to group more than two of those into one single directive. But to be able to determine that, we still don't have enough info from you.)

Comment: "I can't put them in reverse order because I have a few hundred redirects" - I'm curious to know what you would imagine to be an easier fix? (Your [code editor might even have a keyboard shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640721/visual-studio-key-strokes-swapping-lines) to do just that.)