# Visual Studio 2008 move selected text (Alt+Up/Down)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, macros

Is there any Macro, AddIn or something else, that let me do the "Move of the selected text" like in VS2015?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11882672/11683

Comment: Is for VS2012, I need it with VS2008 and it hasn't got Productivity PowerTools.

Comment: You can follow links from there, e.g. to http://stackoverflow.com/a/973111/11683 which is a macro that I believe was supported in 2008.

Comment: The macro doesn't work in VS2008. Thanks.